# Is there a faster way of implementing this 'ranking' algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Lets Suppose I have an array of arrays, where each sub array represents a ranking i.e

```
std::array<std::array<std::string, 4>, 3> rankings = {
  { "A", "C", "B", "D" }, 
  { "C", "D", "B", "A" }, 
  { "B", "A", "D", "C" }
};
```

where in this case we have three 'rankings', with the first ranking being: A 1st, C 2nd, B 3rd, and D 4th, and so  on for the other two rankings.

Now lets say, each place carries the following weights:

- 1st = 8pts
- 2nd = 6pts
- 3rd = 4pts
- 4th = 0pts

My goal is to find out how many points each value (A,B,C,D) scored, in this case the answer is:

- A = 14pts
- B = 16pts
- C = 14pts
- D = 10pts

My implementation of the design is as so:

```
std::map<std::string, size_t> results;

for(auto& ranking : rankings) {
  for(auto i = 0; i < std::distance(ranking.begin(), ranking.end()); ++i) {
     switch(i) {
       case(0) : 
          if(results.find(ranking[i]) != results.end())
            results[ranking[i]] += 8;
          else
            results[ranking[i]] = 8;
          break;
       case(1) : 
          if(results.find(ranking[i]) != results.end())
            results[ranking[i]] += 6;
          else
            results[ranking[i]] = 6;
          break;
       case(2) : 
          if(results.find(ranking[i]) != results.end())
            results[ranking[i]] += 4;
          else
            results[ranking[i]] = 4;
          break;
       default:
          if(results.find(ranking[i]) == results.end())
            results[ranking[i]] = 0;
          break;
      }
   }
}
```

Now, this works fine, but I feel like there's probably a way to improve it since each time you want to add some points to the current total you have to `std::map::find` whether the entry already exists, and that function itself is 'slow', let alone calling it every cycle of the loop ...

One further disclaimer is that I dont actually know what "A","B","C" & "D" are at compile time, they just represent 4 strings, which could be anything.

If anyone has any ideas on a more effective implementation id love to hear, thanks.

Comment: Why the convolution?
Ranking3 Prime is the essence A permute function is 2 calls away?E.g. the set {0,1,2,3} is {4,3,2,1} etc

Why all the extra space?

Is permuted is just 1 bit?

Comment: @Jay do you mind expanding on what you mean?

Comment: See my Answer...

Comment: `std::map::operator[]` is precisely designed to avoid those pesky ifs you have. When you guys will read documentation? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at especially look into example of counting words.

Comment: "let alone calling it every cycle of the loop ..." yea calling it twice every iteration...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we can make your code significantly shorter:

```
auto weights = std::vector<int> { 8, 6, 4 };

std::map<std::string, size_t> results;
for( const auto& ranking : rankings) 
    for(auto i = 0U; i < ranking.size(); ++i) 
       results[ ranking[i] ] += i < weights.size() ? weights[i] : 0;
```

Now we not only made it shorter but fixed 2 issues in your code:

```
1. you did two lookups in every iteration (`std::map::find` and `std::map::operator[]`, for `std::map` of this size it is probably irrelevant but you already has concerns about `std::map::find` speed.

2. You handle i in your switch improperly, you started from 1 but should from 0, I am not sure how your code "works" fine.
```

If you need further speed improvements I woulod suggest to use `std::unordered_map` instead and maybe you would need to copy it back to `std::map` afterwards to sort elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's much cleaner at the very least - and correct! I'll fix the error in my code, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use a vector rather than a array?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> rankings = {
        { "A", "C", "B", "D" },
        { "C", "D", "B", "A" },
        { "B", "A", "D", "C" }
    };
    std::map<std::string, size_t> results;

    for (size_t i{0}; i < rankings.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j{0}; j < rankings[0].size() - 1; ++j)
        {
            results[rankings[i][j]] += 8 - 2 * j;
        }
    }

    for (const auto &[k, v] : results)
    {
        std::cout << "results[\"" << k << "\"] = " << v << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
results["A"] = 14
results["B"] = 16
results["C"] = 14
results["D"] = 10
```